# What does the compilation error "SIG_BLOCK undeclared" mean?

Tags: c, gcc, ubuntu-14.04

I get an error message `error: ‘SIG_BLOCK’ undeclared` for this code when compiling with `-ansi`.

`sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &my_sig, NULL);`

Did I forget to be explicit about some header file? These are my includes

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? And what is the command line set of instructions passed to the compiler? The warning might be removed by passing the right command line arguments to your compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler you want `SIG_BLOCK` to be defined.

From [`man sigaction`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html):

> Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see [feature_test_macros(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html)):
>
> ```
>   sigprocmask(): _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 1 || _XOPEN_SOURCE || _POSIX_SOURCE
> ```

So you might like to pass the option

```
-D_POSIX_SOURCE
```

or

```
-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=1
```

to gcc for example

Alternativly you can put those "requests" as preprocessor directives right at the top of your sources:

```
#define _POSIX_SOURCE
... /* other includes */
#include <signal.h>
```

or

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 1
 ... /* other includes */
#include <signal.h>
```